# Adding char to int in Java

Tags: java, casting, char, int

I have been trying to attach a char 'F' to an int being 1 in a java program but when I do the output is 71. I understand that it is using the ASCII value for F being 70 and then adding 1 producing 71. However, I have tried different attempts at typecasting but cannot get it to produce 1F instead of 71? Any and all help is appreciated.

My code looks like:

```
    public boolean enqueue(int item){

    int first = (char) 'F';
    int comb = (char) (item + first);
    if(currentSize[0] < 6 || currentSize[1] < 6 || currentSize[2] < 6){

        if(currentSize[0] <= currentSize[1] && currentSize[0] <= currentSize[2]){
            Customers[0][back[0]] = comb; //code I am trying to get to produce 1F
            back[0]++;
            currentSize[0]++;
            if (currentSize[0] == 6)
                back[0] = 0;
            else if(back[0] == 6)
                back[0] = 0;
            }
```

--Mike

Comment: Convert the number to a String before adding.

Comment: You confuse me: are you saying that you want 1 + 'F' to be 1F?? If so, why?

Comment: `1F` is a hexadecimal (base 16) representation of an int.  Since hex digits can only be 0–9 and A–F, using an int to represent an arbitary digit and character pair is not likely to work the way you expect it to.  Just make a simple class with two fields instead.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to convert your integer to a string before combining them as Carcigenicate mentioned.

This would look something like

```
int item = 1;
char first = 'F';
String comb = Integer.toString(item) + first;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help.
First of all, you don't have to typecast 'F' character.

Sencond, change variable comb's type to String.

This is the code.

```
int first = 'F';
int item = 1;
String comb = item + Character.toString((char)first);
System.out.println(comb) // 1F
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear what you want, but I hope this helps a bit:

An int variable can only hold numeric values no characters.
A char (character) holds basically a numeric value, too. 
A char is a value between 0 and 255 (1 Byte). But these numbers represent specific symbols. You should take a look at an [ASCII-table](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.asciitbl.com%2F_site_media%2Fascii%2Fascii-chars-table-landscape.jpg&f=1).

If you want to save "1F" in a variable you should take a string or if you want to stick to chars, take a char array.

e.g.:

```
public boolean enqueue(int item){

    char    first   =   'F';
    String  comb    =   String.valueOf(item) + first;
    //After this comb is: "1F" if item is 1

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code below to have the required result.

```
public class Question02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        enqueue(1);
    }

    public static void enqueue(int item) {
        char first = 'F';
        String comb = new Integer(item).toString().concat(new Character(first).toString());
        System.out.println(comb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't exactly know what you're trying to achieve, but if you tried casting and stuff already, why don't you make both String and just concat them?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.